# Should a person refuse to go to a conference when not being paid wages (only travel costs)?

Tags: salary, conferences

My girlfriend currently works part time as a contractor for a family friend. He has asked her to attend a conference on his behalf. The offer is along the lines of "I'll pay your flights for a 'holiday' to x location and you do me a favor by attending the conference'. Which on the face of it might seem like a fair deal.

However, she won't be paid any wages at all while she is there, so she will actually lose money by going.  She also had no plans to go on a holiday at that time or to that place.

Importantly, the conference is applicable to her employer but not her (it is about software his business uses), she has no interest in attending it and it would not help her career directly.

She seems to think this is a great opportunity, I have doubts about legality (this is in the UK) and just in general. I think she is being carried away by the exotic location and potential 'holiday' and not thinking critically about what her time is worth. I feel that she is being exploited, is this an unfair situation being dressed up as a great opportunity?

Comment: Is this conference during a normal working day, or in a weekend? If the former, will she be using a holiday for it?

Comment: I just checked and it is on a weekday that she wouldn't normally work.

Comment: the fact it's on a day off changes everything, and invalidates your question: she's not losing anything, she's getting free travel in exchange for a favor. It could be a good way to endear oneself to the boss. It might ring a little of "time-share scam vacation", and an off-work agreement could be pejoratively cast as "subversive", but it's certainly not exploitation if she only gains from it (being on a day off anyway).

Comment: why are you looking for anonymous group support to challenge your girlfriend - surely she can make her own decision? if she - who works with the boss, in the industry - if she thinks it is a great opportunity... why doubt her? There are plenty of truly great opportunities that put someone at a minor financial disadvantage. Your penultimate sentence - "i think she is being carried away..." smacks of condescension. And as @dandavis notes, she doesn't even work that day.

Comment: *she has no interest in attending it and it would not help her career directly. [...] no plans to go on a holiday at that time or to that place*
- How does that match with those statements:
*She seems to think this is a great opportunity [...]  the exotic location and potential 'holiday'*

Comment: Putting this on hold. It's hard for us to estimate what is and isn't a good opportunity for any particular person's career. It's especially hard when we're asked to make that call in a question by proxy.

Comment: It sounds like the boss instead said, *"You're off on day X, do you want to attend this conference? I'll pay the ticket and airfare if you just attend."* As opposed to viewing it as getting "unpaid" when she's off work that day anyway. Sort of like saying the company has a picnic on your offday and if you'd like to attend you're welcome to come, they'll pay for food. It's not "unpaid work."

Answer (score 5):

Just because you're not being paid for a conference, doesn't automatically mean you shouldn't go. I've been to a number of conferences in weekends, and I don't get paid for them. I just go because I think they're useful to me, and the company agrees enough to pay for the ticket. I think this is a fair deal, given that both of us have something to gain from me being there.

However, this applies *only* to conferences that are actually useful to attend. In this case, your girlfriend was asked by her boss, the boss probably has expectations of what she is going to be doing on the conference, and she does not think the conference is useful for herself.

In that case, it's pretty much work just work. It won't be a holiday, and in such a case I'd turn down the offer unless I was paid to go and all the other costs would be reimbursed.